# How to request, & output JSON from local browser storage using AJAX (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, local-storage

Is it posible to request a JSON object from my browsers local storage with Ajax? it's just a simple object that i made with Js, and converted into JSON.
I then stored it to local browser storage, but i'm not sure that will work, considering that it might only work to request from a server.

I have seen simular questions about this, but i only see examples of jQuery, not pure JavaScript and AJAX.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var info = {

        name: "Josh",
        age: 22,
        born: "New York"
    };

    var jason = JSON.stringify(info);
    localStorage.setItem("myJason", jason)

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET", "file:///D:/HTML%20Files/Nettside%20med%20JSON%20og%20AJAX/nettside.html", true);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    http.send();
```

Comment: You can't do that because of security, the only way is to use new API where you grant permission to disk, but I can't find that API right now.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  You set an item in local storage, can't you just get the item from local storage?

Comment: Here is the API: [HTML5: FileSystem API – Create Files and Store Them Locally Using JavaScript and Webkit](https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit/) the other way is to open a file using input type and read it, for this you can check this [Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/). You don't have access to `file:///`

Comment: For Ajax to work you need to setup local HTTP server like Apache or Nginx. On windows there is [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) meta package.

Comment: Do you want to test any JSON or your own. If then former https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the html file from the local disk then yes you can access it by navigating the file structure using "../" to go up a file, however if the HTML file has been loaded from a web server then the only way to access it is to use a file input and then read the file contents. The user must choose the file though.

Here is an article on reading binary data from a file that the user has selected.
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/